# Modifying a GUI to support FTPS (explicit or implicit) connections, what extra fields do I need to display to user?

Tags: c#, ftps, chilkat, chilkat-ftp

Hi I am adding FTPS support to an existing WinForms GUI that already had standard FTP support. So the existing GUI already has fields for Host, Port, Username, Password.

I use a 3rd party control (chilkat FTP) to manage the actual FTP connections, and it does support FTPS. Also using Filezilla Server to test with.

Going forward I'd like to support standard FTP and FTPS (both explicit and implicit) on this form.

What I'd like to know is, what extra fields do I need to display to the user?

Currently I am going with one checkbox that is labelled "Use FTPS", and a second checkbox labelled "Use implicit connection" which, if checked, changes the port from 21 to 990, unless modified by the user.

Some specific questions I have regarding FTPS connections:

- Is it possible to just tell the server to always TRY to use explicit FTPS, and then fall back on FTP if not available? That would negate the need for the "Use FTPS" checkbox since it would always try to as long as the server supported it. Then, I would only need the "implicit" checkbox.
- Is the only difference with "implicit", the port number being specified to 990?
- Does FTPS allow anonymous connections?
- Anything else I need to worry about?

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: what ftp library are you using on the .net side?

Comment: Chilkat FTP. FTPS connections work if I just set the "AuthTLS" property to true, OR if I set the port to 990. Thats of course with my limited experience setting up filezilla as a secure FTP server. Seems to work though.